# Finding the number of elements of order 2 in $D_{n}$

Tags: finite-groups, cyclic-groups

> Question:
>   If *d* is a positive integer, *d* $\neq 2$ and *d* divides n, show that the number of elements of order *d* in $D_{n}$ is $\phi \left ( d \right )$.
>   How many elements of order 2 does $D_{n}$ have?
>
> Theorem:
>   If *d* is a positive divisor of n, the number of elements of order d in a cyclic group of order n is $\left \langle d \right \rangle$.

$D_{n}$ has order 2n.

*d* is a positive integer and *d* divides n so there exists a subgroup, say $\left \langle a \right \rangle$, of order *d*.

Hints are appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: $D_n$ is not cyclic.

Comment: $D_n$ has two kinds of element, the rotations and the flips. What can you say about the set of all rotations (including the identity element)? What can you say about the order of the flips?